# Divergence of integral $\int_{a}^{t} \frac{1}{g-px^{b}} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, improper-integrals

How can I show that 
$$\lim \limits_{t \rightarrow (\frac{g}{p})^{1/b}}{\int_{a}^{t}} \frac{1}{g-px^{b}} dx ,$$ $g =  $gravitational acceleration, $p,b >0$ diverges to $\infty$ ?

Comment: What have you tried? and btw there's a typo in the title

Comment: Are you referring to the dismissal of 'lim' in the title or am I overseeing something?

Comment: I considered shifting the function somehow to get an easier one and thought about a diverging function g with $abs(g) < f$ ( f function above ). I abandoned this try because this limit seems to be tailored actually for this function.

Comment: For your first question: the was one curly brace to much, so the formula wouldn't compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x_0 = (\frac{g}{p})^{1/b}$. Note that $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{x_0 -  x}{g - px^b} =^H \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{-1}{ - pbx^{b-1}} = \frac{1}{pb}x_0^{-\frac{1}{b}+1} = \frac{1}{gb}x_0^{-\frac{1}{b}} > 0$$
is finite and not equal $0$. That means that if you pick any $C\in(0,\frac{1}{gb}x_0^{-\frac{1}{b}})$, then for $x$ close enough to $x_0$ you have:
$$ C\frac{1}{x_0-x} \le \frac{1}{g - px^b} $$
Since integral $ \int_a^{x_0} \frac{1}{x_0-x} dx $ is divergent this means that also $ \int_a^{x_0} \frac{1}{g-px^b} dx$ is divergent.